# Gcloud push error : ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to push my docker image to gcloud for my kubernetes but i've got the following error

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): No JSON object could be decoded

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to remove the file .dockercfg from the home user...

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1005); please follow that issue for updates.

The error should be intermittent, so you should be able to try again.